# Old laptop won't boot from live CDs

Tags: boot, hardware, livecd

I've got an old Pentium III based Dell Laptop, the originally shipped with Windows 2K and has had Windows XP installed on it. I though I could get something useful out of it if I run Puppy, Lubuntu, or CrunchBang on it. I've created live CDs for each of the distros. I've test the CDs in other machines and the CDs are fine. But when I put them in the laptop, it won't boot.

The machine powers on and runs the self test. At that point, I can tell that it is reading the CD, but nothing ever happens. As far as I know the CD drive is fine.

I have confirmed that in the BIOS, the machine will boot from the optical drive.

#### Questions

- Is there anything else I should check in the BIOS?
- Are there other distributions that are better for older laptops?

Comment: Have you tried a LiveUSB instead? It may be a problem with you drive (I know you said it's fine, but we should check)

Comment: From looking at the BIOS setting, I don't believe that the laptop can boot from a USB drive.

Comment: Have you tried creating an installation DVD (not LiveCD)?

Comment: @DavidsonChua For these small distros, the LiveCD is the installation media as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I would try [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/). I've had good luck with it running on older hardware in the past, especially when booting it as a LiveCD. Also I might try using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to install an ISO onto a USB thumbdrive and boot the system using that instead.

[image: ss of unetbootin]

Comment: +1. Knoppix has excellent hardware detection, and a USB is a good way of troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: a USB won't work, since OP stated (after this answer was written) that his BIOS doesn't do USB boot.

Comment: @strugee - thanks, he didn't mention that originally. I've used USB installations on P3 system before, so it is possible w/ that series of CPUs + MoBo's.

Comment: UNetbootin an awesome app. +1 fa ya.